# Rewrite routes in angular e.g. ....com/de/de-de/ to ...com/de/de_DE/

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Is there any way in angular to easily rewrite urls in the router before it actually tries to match the urls to its modules/components?

My goal is to rewrite the locales of an url like **de-de** to **de_DE**.

As this is statically hosted I can't use the server to do the rewriting.

I am not sure if using a guard would be the right thing to do. I though of hooking in earlier.

Any hints would be much appreciated :) Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a .htaccess

Something like:

```
Redirect /de-de /de_DE/
```

Depending on how many languages you have and where this occurs in your url etc. you might have to do something more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer unfortunately this wont work as this is hosted on a cdn and the rewrite rules are limited there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a guard which is rewriting the pathname